# VBA For loop until column is empty problem

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying this for loop out, but I think my "To" counter is wrong. I want it to perform the specified actions until there are no more columns left to cut.

What is happening is, I have a horizontal set of data(Column "T" to "EV") that I am cutting and pasting in order vertically on column S. It works, but I get this error still:

I get:

Run-time error '1004':

This selection is not valid.
There are several possible reasons:

- Copy and paste areas cannot overlap unless they're the same size and shape.
- If you are using the Create from Selection command, the row or column containing the proposed names won't be included in the(cuts off here)

Code:

```
Dim x As Integer

For x = 0 To ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, x).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("S3000").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("T11").Select

Next x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, written directly here, but it should work...

```
dim c as range
for each c in range("t1").currentregion
    range("s3000").end(xlup).offset(1,0)= c.value
    c.clear
next c
```

There's no point changing the active cell. It just slows down your code.

Comment: Tried it, but I get, Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. It highlights the "range("s3000").end(xlup).offset(1,0).paste" line when I debug

Comment: In @iDevlop code there's a comma where (I believe) we should have a dot.

Comment: I changed the comma to a dot. I caught the error. thanks though

Comment: Just checked here, and there's no 'paste' method for the range object, but 'PasteSpecial'. I'll do the edit in the @iDevlop code in the way (I believe) it might work...
Edit: Done, pending iDevlop approval. Still, using cut and paste is not recommended, as the clipboard is shared with other applications...

Comment: Run-time error: '1004': 

PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

Comment: ok. I edited it in a different (faster ?) way, no copy/paste.

Comment: LOL. That actually went down and deleted my rows. Not sure what is going on. Thanks everybody for all of your help. I think I might just leave this one since my code did work for the most part, but I'll just have to deal with the error code at the end.

Comment: well, Lee, that code works, I tested it. If just copy/paste and you don't try to understand it, there's no point!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the built-in TRANSPOSE worksheet function to achieve this - see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/transpose-function-HP010342964.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010342655)

If you want to achieve this using VBA then, as Tiago Cardoso pointed out, using cut and paste is generally not the best solution. Consider using the `Cells` method of the `Worksheet` object and keeping track of which column and which row you are working with.